# Using low GPU priority for background rendering

Tags: ios, gpu

How to debug *"Using low GPU priority for background rendering."*

I see on console of an app using `AVFoundation` on iOS8 beta4?

I suppose I'm doing some unneeded work that I could skip saving the battery
and eliminating the message I've tripped

Comment: This happens when you're doing tasks of rendering in the background. I'm experiencing the same, but didn't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

according to [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html), iOS does not allow its `GPU` to any background application for obvious reason that its not on `Foreground`.

Comment: Right, it does not allow you to render to a framebuffer attached to screen. But as you can see the process is alive and well, meaning that it does some background rendinging and does not get killed. Now, it's not very useful in a large app not having a way to break in debugger on this condition, is it?

Comment: To think of it. Since my app does not use GLES directly this is probably tripped by CoreImage or some other apple framework sitting on top of GLES

Comment: i guess its for all, I mean how could iOS allow rendering even in alive application to use GPU when its in control of OS not your app